# How do you stop a event from effecting an image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the on method to attach a 'click' event to a button to toggle a gallery...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.galleryContainer').hide();

       $('.myButtons').on("click", function(e) {
        $('.galleryContainer').toggle(400);
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      });
    });
```

The problem is, it's effecting the functionality of the gallery (i.e. clicking on the thumbnail of the gallery is causing the toggle function to fire...)

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="alpha sixteen columns omega">
 <h2>Engagements</h2>
  <div id="myWorkEngagements" class="scale-with-grid"></div>
   <a href="#" class="myButtons ">press me</a>                                             

        <p class="coreParagraph">
      Skeleton is built on three core principles:
    </p>

   <ul class="galleryContainer gallery">
          <li><a href="images/weddingImages/full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/weddingImages/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" class="myButtons"></a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a href="images/weddingImages/full/002.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/weddingImages/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" class="myButtons"></a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div><!-- eight columns -->
```

Comment: can you put some html code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the same class `myButtons` to the thumbnail images so the click handler will fire because of the selector is based on this class.

Try assigning another class to the images like `myButtons2`

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="alpha sixteen columns omega">
         <h2>Engagements</h2>

        <div id="myWorkEngagements" class="scale-with-grid"></div> <a href="#" class="myButtons ">press me</a> 
        <p class="coreParagraph">Skeleton is built on three core principles:</p>
        <ul class="galleryContainer gallery">
            <li><a href="images/weddingImages/full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/weddingImages/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" class="myButtons2"></a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="images/weddingImages/full/002.jpg" rel="external"><img src="images/weddingImages/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" class="myButtons2"></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- eight columns -->
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/856FL/

Comment: Hey Irvin,
Completely overlooked the class on the images! Thanks!
I am trying to condense these galleries into the 'my work.html' page, (http://localhost/mirophotography/my_work.html)and I kind of like the .toggle method...